# Moved magento site & get a fatal error when I try to access the backend > config

Tags: php, magento, configuration, magento-1.7, fatal-error

I moved our existing Magento site to my hosting account for development work but when I try to access anywhere on the backend of the site other than the admin dashboard I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element' not found in /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 491
```

In the database `core_config_data table` I've changed the `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` to match the new domain name.

In the `.htaccess` file I've changed the `RewriteBase /` to use the new folder path.

The error I'm getting refers to line 491 in the Layout.php file which is the 4th `if` clause of the below function:

```
/**
 * Create block object instance based on block type
 *
 * @param string $block
 * @param array $attributes
 * @return Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
 */
protected function _getBlockInstance($block, array $attributes=array())
{
    if (is_string($block)) {
        if (strpos($block, '/')!==false) {
            if (!$block = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName($block)) {
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid block type: %s', $block));
            }
        }
        if (class_exists($block, false) || mageFindClassFile($block)) {
            $block = new $block($attributes);
        }
    }
    if (!$block instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid block type: %s', $block));
    }
    return $block;
}
```

Comment: check if file exists in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Renderer/Fieldset/Element.php? it looks like magento cant access block class

Comment: @waldek_c Thank you, that solved it perfectly :)  It existed but was totally empty, so I just copied the original into it

Comment: @waldek_c I see now that the `Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element'` is the path to the file  causing the issue

Comment: yes it's Zend naming conevntion, `_` is equal `/` in real path :)

Comment: But my doubt is, how does the core file function got removed? Do you worked on that file earlier? How the function will automatically got removed?

Comment: @PavanKumar I transferred the site with ftp, it's a large magento site & I had a poor internet connection.  I believe the file was not transferred properly.  Infact, I believe other files where missed in the transfer, so I will have to delete the site & upload it again.  I'm going to upload a compressed version of the site, hopefully that will be faster & will not miss anything.

Comment: Aaa Here is the point. When ever you transfer site from local to server, u must do with zipped files. I think u got it now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@waldek_c comment above really helped me solve this but i thought I put an answer up myself to complete the question in case anyone else ran into something similar.

The error message itself was pointing me to the issue.

`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element` was the path to the file causing the issue.  As it turned out the file did not upload correctly when I was uploading the site.